# Why does real world MapReduce jobs tend to have very small dataset sizes?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

All the papers I have read suggest real world mapreduce jobs tend to operate on relatiely small data set sizes (mostly map only, tend to operate on KB-16GB for vast majority of jobs). If anyone working in production world could talk about how and why smaller data set tends to be the case, I would understand better. For small dataset (<128MB), are the files tend to be fragmented or contigous because it has some implication on the splits and number of map tasks spawned ? And if hadoop lets mapreduce to operate only on a section of file ?

Any pointers is much appreciated.

Comment: You know, BigData is a lie and some kind of marketing gag ;)

Comment: Yeah. Seems to be true :) BigData is big in storage, not necessarily compute.

Comment: The question is : Why is hadoop applied to small data sets too ? or Are there any really big data sets that motivate the existence of Hadoop-like frameworks ?

Comment: The only reason for running MapReduce on a tiny dataset (<1GB) I can see is if you are doing something very CPU heavy in your Map method. Otherwise it's faster/easier to process it locally. I don't really see people running mapreduces on data that's <100GB

Answer (score 0):

Typically small data is used to quickly check if the logic / code is good enough. The evaluations have to be done again and again until a good solution is obtained.

I work in production and we use small data for unit testing (order of MBs) and we have sample data sets of size 10-30 gigs which we use for integration testing at dev end. But this is way too small considering the actual data dealt with on prod servers (which is in order of terabytes). The dev environment is of low capacity as compared to prod environment so we cannot expect terabytes of data to run smoothly over it... plus its time consuming as it has to be executed for every release.

Moving to technical papers: Authors want real data: that too which is inclined towards the specific use cases that they attempt to solve. Its difficult to obtain huge data sets (10-100 gigs) focused to their problem. I have seen few papers where they used huge data sets but then those researchers where belonged to big companies and can easily get that data.

Comment: TejasP - Could you please provide pointers to huge data set papers ? The ones I have seen are related to log data from facebook/yahoo etc and the average sizes continue to be quite small (<20GB dataset sizes 80%-90% of jobs!). I understand having smaller sizes for dev - but am quite surprised about production systems from the real big guys!